# set static const string as default value of a param and encounters error 1047

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function like

```
public function notify(messageKey:String, messageArgs:Array = null, state:String = NotificationState.INFO):void
```

where

```
public class NotificationState {
    public static const INFO:String = "info";
    public static const WARN:String = "warn";
    public static const ERROR:String = "error";
    public static const SUCCESS:String = "success";

    public function NotificationState() {
        throw new AbstractClassError();
    }
}
```

And this results in an error 1047:Parameter Initializer Unknown Or Is Not A Compile-time Constant

Obviously the `NotificationState.INFO` is a constant string, so it should be a compile-time constant isn't it?

Then why does this error happens?

ps, I'm using Flash Builder 4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly common problem of the ASC's class dependencies as the dependency analysis does **not** include default parameter initializers (never has, never will due to circular references that const parameter initializers can cause in ASC).

- So if you were directly calling ASC you can just move your `NotificationState` class in front of your `notify` class.
- Other ways are to place your consts into a different library and include the resulting SWC were they are needed.
- You can also defined the consts in the same class as they are needed, kind-of ugly, unless you use the `include` directive.
- Flag your CONST only classes as `public final` to provide a hint to the compiler.
- If your CONST class and the class that is using them as default parameter initializers both do not inherit from another class, extend the class that is using the const initializers from some simple base class. ASC 'tends' to compile super classes after base-only classes even if there are *no* dependancies.

Comment: The class which include function notify is a flex module which bases on spark Group

Comment: If hardcoding 'info' as your initializer works it is a compiler dependency issue. I use Intellj-Idea so I do not know if in FB4.7 you can override the compiler order, you can save the compiler output and re-order the files manually since FB is just shelling out to the compiler. I would try placing your consts in a separate `.swc` if using using a hardcoded initializer is not really an option.